# Idiomatic scala way of creating unnamed extracting func

Tags: scala, idioms

Given that there is a function`foo[A, B, C]( func: (a: A, b: B, c: C) => B)` and I want to pass in this function `def secondOfThree[A, B, C](a: A, b: B, c: C): B = b`

I can call `foo` with `foo(secondOfThree)` which is ugly, but works fine.. However, I would expect to be able to call `foo` with something along the lines of `foo(case (_, b, _) => b)` however this doesn't work.

So what's the clean idiomatic scala way of creating a simple unnamed extracting function?

Comment: Why are you trying to pass only 1 argument to foo, which takes 3 arguments? What are you trying to extract this value from - a tuple?

Comment: @LuigiPlinge whoops, sorry. Fixed the signature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `case` keyword, but Scala *does* need to know the types:

```
scala> def foo[A, B, C](func: (A, B, C) => B) = ...
foo: [A, B, C](func: (A, B, C) => B)Nothing

scala> foo[Symbol, Int, Char]((_, b, _) => b)
```

If the types are known to `foo`, then the call doesn't need to specify them:

```
scala> def foo(func: (Symbol, Int, Char) => Int) = func('a, 2, 'c') + 5
foo: (func: (Symbol, Int, Char) => Int)Int

scala> foo((_, b, _) => b)
res3: Int = 7
```

Answer (score 2):

So if types could be inferred, you can just the simplest:

```
class Trio[A, B, C](a: A, b: B, c: C) {
  def foo(func: (A, B, C) => B): B = func(a, b, c)
}

println(new Trio(1, "string", 'Symbol).foo((_, b, _) => b))
```